# How to check ActiveMQ queues in unit test using JUnit Rule with EmbeddedActiveMQBroker

Tags: junit, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I created an Integration test (based on apache camel and blueprint) that sends some messages to an ActiveMQ service on my machine.
Via the admin-web interface i can check if my messages arrived. To decouple from a locally running ActiveMQ i am now using the EmbeddedActiveMQBroker with JUnit Rule (followed instructions from [here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-to-unit-test-jms-code.html)):

```
@Rule
public EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        try {
            this.getBrokerService().addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // noop test should fail
        }
    }
};
```

The test works fine as before.
But: Is there a way to check the number of (queued)messeages for a given queue? The test sends messages to the queue "q".

Answer (score 4):

Your EmbeddedActiveMQBroker instance wraps around an ActiveMQ BrokerService object that is the real embedded ActiveMQ broker.  Because you have access to that through the EmbeddedActiveMQBroker instance you have access to all the stats maintained by the broker via the AdminView (broker.getBrokerService().getAdminView())

From there you can get all sorts of useful info like number of subscriptions, number of Queues etc.  All this data is kept in the broker's JMX management context tree so standard JMX applies.  One easy way to get info on number of messages in a Queue then is to lookup the Queue in the Broker's management context using code similar to the following:

```
// For this example the broker name is assumed to be "localhost"
protected QueueViewMBean getProxyToQueue(String name) throws MalformedObjectNameException, JMSException {
    ObjectName queueViewMBeanName = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue,destinationName="+name);
    QueueViewMBean proxy = (QueueViewMBean) brokerService.getManagementContext()
            .newProxyInstance(queueViewMBeanName, QueueViewMBean.class, true);
    return proxy;
}
```

From there you can use the QueueViewMBean to see what's in the Queue:

```
QueueViewMBean queueView = getProxyToQueue("myQueue");
LOG.info("Number of messages in my Queue:{}", queueView.getQueueSize());
```

It looks as though the current implementation disables JMX by default which is unfortunate but can be worked around.  You have to give the embedded broker instance a configuration URI which is either a string containing the connector to add or an xbean configuration file.

One option would be to do something along these lines (note the useJmx=true):

```
@Rule
public EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker("broker:(tcp://0.0.0.0:0)/localhost?useJmx=true&persistent=false");
```

Comment: Thanks for code but it seems not to work: The method returns an object of desired type but on calling getQueueSize i get an InstanceNotFoundException.

Comment: You might need to ensure that the management context on the embedded broker is enabled.

Comment: how to do this? i also tried to find the mbeans with jconsole but there seems to be nothing about activemaq, while i see all other mbeans.

Comment: Added some more info.  The JUnit embedded bit seems to do the wrong thing and turn off JMX by default.

Comment: How to use it in jUnit5? There is no more @Rule.